# Foundation 6 how to make changes during going over between tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I use Foundation 6 and now I got the problem.
There are 2 tabs "entrance" & "registration" into modal window "authorization".
I want to make such thing "If you fill inputs for example in "registration" tab but don't push button and go over to "entrance" tab, inputs in "registration" tab should be clear".
I wrote this code and tried it but it is not working

```
$("#authorization-tab-link").click(function(){
  $("#register-alert").removeClass("callout alert success").empty();
  $("#email-register-input").val("");
  $("#name-register-input").val("");
  $("#first-password-register-input").val("");
  $("#second-password-register-input").val("");
});
```

I did the same by using bootstrap and it is working. That's odd.
I don't know why `<a>` .click() is not handling.

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/n3sompxu/2/ ?

Comment: That's working.

Comment: Does that solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Foundation6 Documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html), you can use an event to do this:

```
$(document).on('change.zf.tabs',function(){
  $("#register-alert").removeClass("callout alert success").empty();
  $("#email-register-input").val("");
  $("#name-register-input").val("");
  $("#first-password-register-input").val("");
  $("#second-password-register-input").val("");
});
```

Normally this should work. If not, try the `.on()` on your Tab element. e.g.:

```
$('#my-tab-wrapper').on('change.zf.tabs',function(){ /* do stuff here */  });
```

### EDIT:

```
$('#my-tab-wrapper').on('change.zf.tabs', function(e, target){

});
```

Check what the target var returns and build an if/else. This should work .

Comment: First example of code works but for all of tabs, second example works only when i fill whatever input in another tab. Is there variant how to do it on select another tab ?

Comment: Edited my answer. @МихаилМельничук